# After submitting a form commands for next loaded page are not executed in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, casperjs

After submitting a form, I want to fill and submit a second form, but the second time `.then()` is not working, see code below:

Situation is on click "Add new company" button I get a form, after submitting I redirect to another form which I am scripting in another `then()` but it doesn't work from here

```
var casper = require('casper').create(); var config = {
  url: "http://www.example.com",
};
config.form = {
  "subForm_Company_Info[name]": "testCompany",
  "subForm_Company_Info[company_marketing_email]": "me@example.com",
  "subForm_Company_Info[company_industry]":"1",
  "subForm_Company_Info[decision_maker_first_name]":"Asd",
  "subForm_Company_Info[decision_maker_last_name]":"Asd",
  "subForm_Company_Info[decision_maker_email]":"Asd@gmail.com",
  "subForm_Company_Info[decision_maker_phone]":"1122223333"
};
config.marketInfo = {
  "subForm_Company_Info[information_6]": "test",
  "subForm_Company_Info[information_7]": "test",
  "subForm_Company_Info[information_8]": "test",
  "subForm_Company_Info[information_1]": "test",
  "subForm_Company_Info[information_2]": "test",
  "subForm_Company_Info[information_3]": "test",
  "subForm_Company_Info[information_4]": "test",
  "subForm_Company_Info[information_5]": "test"
};
casper.test.begin('Testing navigation and forms', 10, function suite(test) {
    casper.start(config.url,function(){

        this.click('li.right a');
        test.comment('Clicking the Add new company link...');

    })
    .viewport(1360,725);

    casper.then(function(){
        test.comment('open url');
        casper.fill('#submitchanges', config.form, false);
        this.click("button#same");
        this.click("button.submitchanges");
        test.comment('submit form....');
    });

    // its second form which doesn't get execute, execution stops from here, provide the solution

    casper.then(function() {
        test.comment('ENTER*****');
        casper.fill('div#market-information form', config.marketInfo, true);
        test.comment('fill form---..');
    });

    casper.run(function() {
        test.done();
    });

});
```

Comment: How does the execution stop? What do you see? *doesn't work* is not an appropriate description. Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: problem is on submit the first form the another form appears after page reload and url is oldurl/id, and on this url no single function does work

Comment: So, there is no additional information from the events that I suggested? There is not much to go on to solve this.